# Axios return of nested JSON file

Tags: json, vue.js

I am trying to return the 'title' from my JSON file but I can't seem to get the correct path.  At the moment 'resultPacket' is returning info but when I try and get into the 'results - metaData' it's not returning anything.

Can someone help?

**VueJS axios call section**

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      title: "",   
    
    };
  },
  props: {
    result: Object,
  },

mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        "**myURL is here - I cant share**"
      )   
      .then((response) => {
        **this.results = response.data.response.resultPacket;**        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
  },
};
```

**JSON**

```
response": {
    "resultPacket": {      
      "querySystemRaw": null,       
      "results": [
        {
          "rank": 1,
          "score": 1000, 
          "metaData": {           
            "title": "This is the title",
```

Comment: You need to share more code. How do you try to get `'results - metaData'`. Are you doing: `response.resultPacket.results[0].metaData.title`?

Comment: I get a response if I use the code above which stops at 'resultPacket' if I try and add anything further in like 'results' or 'metaData'. No results show. I wondered if it was because 'results' are inside a [] . My assumption would the answer should be 'response.resultPacket.results.metaData.title' but as I mention this doesn't show any results. I hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: response.resultPacket.results returns an array of objects. So as @BTL said, you will need to set the index of the array item you want the metaData.title for.  Are you sure you included the "[0]" after results? **response.resultPacket.results[0].metaData.title**

Comment: I added 'response.resultPacket.results[0].metaData.title ' and get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results').

Comment: I got it  after a little fiddling around and both your helpful tips of '[0] ' .response.data.response.resultPacket.results[0].metaData.title; 

Thanks @BTL & el_M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not fetching the nested property properly from the response you are getting from an API.

Also, As results might contain any number of objects. Hence, you can use loop to iterate from all the result objects.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const data = {
    "response": {
        "resultPacket": {
            "results": [{
                "rank": 1,
                "score": 1000,
                "metaData": {
                    "title": "This is the 1st title"
                }
            }, {
                "rank": 2,
                "score": 1000,
                "metaData": {
                    "title": "This is the 2nd title"
                }
            }, {
                "rank": 3,
                "score": 1000,
                "metaData": {
                    "title": "This is the 3rd title"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      results: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.results = data.response.resultPacket.results;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in results" :key="index">
        {{ item.metaData.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```